# What is the maximal possible rank of $A - I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Given positive integers $k \leq n$, and an arbitrary field F, consider a matrix $A\in \mathbb{M}_n(F)$  that satisfies the following property:
for any non-zero vector $α$ in $F^{n \times 1}$, there exist a k-dimensional affine subspace $β(α) + V(α)$ of $F^{n \times 1}$ containing $α$ but not the origin(i.e. the vector β(α) is not contained in the k-dimensional subspace $V(α)$), such that the image of $β(α) + V(α)$ under left multiplication of $A$ is $V(α)$ itself. The problem is to find the maximum of $rank(A - I)$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

This problem I'm working on generates from the following interesting problem I solved using a few days:
Consider a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$, with subspaces $W_1,...,W_m$, and vectors $α_1,...,α_m$. Assume that
$dim W_i = dim V -1$,
$\cap W_i = \{0\}$,
$α_i ∉ W_i$.
Now suppose $T \in L(V)$ satisfies: for any $i \in \{1,2,...,m\}$, there
exists $j \in \{1,2,...,m\}$ such that $T(α_i + W_i) \subset α_j + W_j$. Show that $det(T) = 1$ or $-1$.

Comment: I think, intuitively, $A$ shouldn't be far from $I$.

Comment: The question does not make much sense. There is no relation between $\alpha$ and $V(\alpha)$ at present. As written all that is assumed is that $A$ acts invertibly on some $k$-dimensional subspace. Well, so does $2I$, so the maximum is $n$ for silly reasons.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to type something. Already fixed.

Comment: My original idea is to consider dual spaces, but the situation became quite complicated for me to handle.

Comment: More specifically, I tried to use the fact that all k-dimensional subspace can be represented as the intersection of the kernel of n-k linear functions on $F^{n \times 1}$.

Comment: I don't see how your edit rules out $2I$, again making the answer "$n$ for silly reasons".

Comment: Sorry again, already fixed. I have to admit, the conditions of this problem is quite complicated for me to remember correctly.